# get value from one table by reference of another table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using MySql and C#. I have two tables with the following structures:

table1: fichas,
column1: matricula (varchar),
column2: lugar (smallint(4))

table2: lugardetrabajo,
column1: referencia (smallint(4)),
column2: nombre (varchar)

I need to get the value of "nombre" based on the reference value "referencia" (both from the table "lugardetrabajo") matching that of the column "lugar" from the table "fichas"

So far my query goes like this:

```
select lugar from fichas where matricula=@matricula

select nombre from lugardetrabajo where referencia=@referencia
```

Comment: There does not appear to be any referential data between the two tables to make the connection from a record in one table to a record (or set of records) in the other. If it is a one to one relationship you'll need a column in the second table referring to a record in the first table. If your relationship is one to many, you may need an intermediate table to hold the references from one table to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Use Join Statement

```
SELECT F.LUGAR, F.MATRICULA L.NOMBRE FROM FICHAS F INNER JOIN LUGARDETRABAJO L ON F.LUGAR = L.REFERENCIA
```